# How to reset the channels and get back to the stable release

Tags: downgrade

I am unable to update, and add repos. I upgraded to Ubuntu 13.10, but it now says I am using the developmental trusty channels, and I need some advice on how to reset the channels and get back to the stable release.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. There isn't a "safe" way to downgrade packages between releases. The only way is a total reinstall of the system.